# Mac: Script application downloaded from the Internet

Tags: macos, file-management

I downloaded a php framework and has started to make a website using that. Sometimes I need to look at the source of that framework and every time I open a file I haven't opened before I get this message:

> “somefile.php” is a script application which was downloaded from the Internet. Are you sure you want to open it?

That is ok and nice I suppose, but I am getting tired of it. Is there a way I can fix all the files in my web directory so that the os somehow forgets the files are from the Internet or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this discussion](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20071029151619619) about Mac OS X extended file attributes. OS X puts a `com.apple.quarantine` attribute on downloaded files.

You can use `find` and `xattr` to clear that.

Comment: That seems to have been it. Used `find . -exec xattr -d com.apple.quarantine {} \;` in my web folder to unset it on all files. Think it worked :p